# How to check if the filename already exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need little help to modify my function. How can I check if the file already exists with the same name? and if it does then to add a newguid string to the name and save the new file.

```
public string UploadStorageFile(StorageModel newFile, int userId)
{
    string uniqueFileName = null;
    if(newFile.FileName != null)
    {
        string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, $"repositories/{userId}");
        if (!Directory.Exists(uploadsFolder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadsFolder);
        }
        uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + newFile.FileName.FileName;
        string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);
        using(var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            newFile.FileName.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }

    return uniqueFileName;
}
```

Comment: Soo, you've successfully put a Directory.Exists in your code; why not try the obvious thing for file?

Comment: By the way, creating a directory that already exists is a no-op; you don't need the Directory.Exists check first

Comment: Keep in mind you have a potential concurrency issue. You can use `File.Exists()` but the file may not exist one millisecond then a second user uploads a file of the same name before your code continues. It may be quite unlikely depending on your use case, but be aware of the possibility.

Answer (score 1):

For Checking, if a File already exists, you can use the `File.Exists()` method.

Here is a basic example, on how to check if a File does already exist:

```c
    public bool DoesFileAlreadyExist(string uploadFolder, string fileName)
    {
        var file = $"{uploadFolder}\{fileName}";
        return File.Exists(file);
    }
```

Specific on your Code, you could use the method like in this example (Just call the method, and check if it is existing):

```cs
public string UploadStorageFile(StorageModel newFile, int userId)
{
    string uniqueFileName = null;
    if(newFile.FileName != null)
    {
        string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, $"repositories/{userId}");
        if (!Directory.Exists(uploadsFolder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadsFolder);
        }

        if (!DoesFileAlreadyExist(uploadsFolder, newFile.Filename)
        {
        
        uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + newFile.FileName.FileName;
        string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);
        using(var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            newFile.FileName.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }

    return uniqueFileName;
    }
return "NO FILE CREATED";
}
```